# creating columns with continuous values on individual csv files

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I have a large csv file which I have split into six individual files. I am using a 'for loop' to read each file and create a column
in which the values ascend by one.

```
whole_file=['100Hz1-raw.csv','100Hz2-raw.csv','100Hz3-raw.csv','100Hz4-raw.csv','100Hz5-raw.csv','100Hz6-raw.csv']

first_file=True

for piece in whole_file:
    if not first_file:
        skip_row = [0] # if it is not the first csv file then skip the header row (row 0) of that file
    else:
        skip_row = []
    V_raw = pd.read_csv(piece)
    V_raw['centiseconds'] = np.arange(len(V_raw)) #label each centisecond
```

[My output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCF3k.png)

[My desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef3vR.png)

Is there a clever way of doing what I intend.

Comment: Please copy/paste the data instead of uploading images

Comment: You could create an empty pandas dataframe and append each file in a for loop over the list of .csv files you have stored within a list.

Comment: the problem is that if I append all the files together, I will run out of memory, thus I need it to be done chunk by chunk.

Comment: Because the data frame is too big?

Comment: yes, it is 10gb. I want to process them individually but for that, I need the centiseconds to be labelled continuously.

Comment: Then you maybe want to store it as a numpy array as this requires less memory

Comment: @Julemb95 could you please select the answer that you found helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the last value for centiseconds and count from there:

```py
whole_file=['100Hz1-raw.csv','100Hz2-raw.csv','100Hz3-raw.csv','100Hz4-raw.csv','100Hz5-raw.csv','100Hz6-raw.csv']

first_file=True

## create old_centiseconds variable
old_centiseconds = 0

for piece in whole_file:
    if not first_file:
        skip_row = [0] # if it is not the first csv file then skip the header row (row 0) of that file
    else:
        skip_row = []
    V_raw = pd.read_csv(piece)

    # add old_centiseconds onto what you had before
    V_raw['centiseconds'] = np.arange(len(V_raw)) + old_centiseconds #label each centisecond

    # update old_centiseconds
    old_centiseconds += len(V_raw)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment you may want to view the data as a numpy array as this requires less memory. You can this by opening the .csv files as numpy array and then append to an empty list. If you would like to append these numpy arrays together you can `.vstack`. The following code should be able to do this:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt

whole_file=['100Hz1-raw.csv','100Hz2-raw.csv','100Hz3-raw.csv','100Hz4-raw.csv','100Hz5-raw.csv','100Hz6-raw.csv']

whole_file_numpy_array = []

for file_name in whole_file:
    
    my_data = genfromtxt(file_name, delimiter=',')
    
    whole_file_numpy_array.append(file_name)
    
combined_numpy_array = np.vstack(whole_file_numpy_array)
```